# Best way to handle JSON with occasional string data in numeric field?

Tags: json, swift, codable, jsondecoder

I wonder if someone could help me out with the best way to handle a type that should be numeric but occasionally shows as string.

[image]

This has only just started happening, the struct that I am using is below, I can't fix this on the server, but obviously the inconsistant data is crashing JSONDecoder

```
struct CountryInfo: Codable {
    var iso2: String
    var iso3: String
    var _id: Int
    var lat: Double
    var long: Double
    var flag: String
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT: sample.json ADDED**

Notice in China _id = 156 but in Iran _id = "NO DATA"

[{"country":"China","countryInfo":{"iso2":"CN","iso3":"CHN","_id":156,"lat":35,"long":105,"flag":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NovelCOVID/API/master/assets/flags/cn.png"},"cases":81171,"todayCases":78,"deaths":3277,"todayDeaths":7,"recovered":73159,"active":4735,"critical":1573,"casesPerOneMillion":56,"deathsPerOneMillion":2},{"country":"Italy","countryInfo":{"iso2":"IT","iso3":"ITA","_id":380,"lat":42.8333,"long":12.8333,"flag":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NovelCOVID/API/master/assets/flags/it.png"},"cases":69176,"todayCases":5249,"deaths":6820,"todayDeaths":743,"recovered":8326,"active":54030,"critical":3393,"casesPerOneMillion":1144,"deathsPerOneMillion":113},{"country":"USA","countryInfo":{"iso2":"NO DATA","iso3":"NO DATA","_id":"NO DATA","lat":0,"long":0,"flag":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NovelCOVID/API/master/assets/flags/unknow.png"},"cases":49976,"todayCases":6242,"deaths":634,"todayDeaths":81,"recovered":368,"active":48974,"critical":1175,"casesPerOneMillion":151,"deathsPerOneMillion":2},{"country":"Spain","countryInfo":{"iso2":"ES","iso3":"ESP","_id":724,"lat":40,"long":-4,"flag":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NovelCOVID/API/master/assets/flags/es.png"},"cases":39676,"todayCases":4540,"deaths":2800,"todayDeaths":489,"recovered":3794,"active":33082,"critical":2355,"casesPerOneMillion":849,"deathsPerOneMillion":60},{"country":"Germany","countryInfo":{"iso2":"DE","iso3":"DEU","_id":276,"lat":51,"long":9,"flag":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NovelCOVID/API/master/assets/flags/de.png"},"cases":32781,"todayCases":3725,"deaths":156,"todayDeaths":33,"recovered":3133,"active":29492,"critical":23,"casesPerOneMillion":391,"deathsPerOneMillion":2},{"country":"Iran","countryInfo":{"iso2":"NO DATA","iso3":"NO DATA","_id":"NO DATA","lat":0,"long":0,"flag":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NovelCOVID/API/master/assets/flags/unknow.png"},"cases":24811,"todayCases":1762,"deaths":1934,"todayDeaths":122,"recovered":8913,"active":13964,"critical":0,"casesPerOneMillion":295,"deathsPerOneMillion":23}]

Comment: Please post json as text and not as an image. Are you sure it is received as string sometimes or is it just the default type shown in the UI when a value is nil?

Comment: I think this is a problem with the server and the way the data is being amalgamated. I was just interested to learn if there was a way to fix this in the struct that I was not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom `init(from)` where you try to decode the _id using `try?` to make the result optional which means you need to change the declaration of the property to be optional

```
struct Country: Decodable {
    let country: String
    let countryInfo: CountryInfo
}
struct CountryInfo: Decodable {
    var iso2: String
    var iso3: String
    var id: Int?
    var lat: Double
    var long: Double
    var flag: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case iso2, iso3
        case id = "_id"
        case lat, long, flag
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        iso2 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .iso2)
        iso3 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .iso3)
        id = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        lat = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .lat)
        long = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .long)
        flag = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .flag)
    }
}
```

I would also opt for making any property optional where the API might return "NO DATA" since I think `nil` is clearer and easier to handle later on.